# How to embed `diff2html` into a node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, diff2html

I am new to node.js and would like to come up with an application using the [diff2html](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html) package. Could anybody tell me how a minimalistic implementation could look like (perhaps by completing the code below)?

```
var http = require('http');
var diff2html = require("diff2html").Diff2Html

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // more code here
}).listen(123456);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only two methods, both are described in the [documentation](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html#how-to-use).

The lib is for converting a existing diff to html. So there are the two methods getPrettyHtml() and getJsonFromDiff().

I'm not sure what you want to do, but it would be something like:

```
var http = require('http');
var diff2html = require("diff2html").Diff2Html

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    diff2html.getPrettyHtml(YOUR_DIFF_FROM_SOMEWHERE, YOUR_OPTIONS);
}).listen(123456);
```